# Adding scrolllistener to a recyclerview and hide a view on another layout

Tags: android, android-layout, android-fragments, listener

I have some fragments let's say A, B, and C. I get the corresponding layouts for these fragments using `inflate` method.

In A and B, I have a Recycler View which I tend to add a Scroll Listener. Also, in fragment C, I have a view (let's say a tablayout) which I want to hide/show it by scrolling the recycler views (which are in A and B).

I am not sure how can I achieve that. Since the `tablayout` is in the layout of fragment C (and not in A and B).

I was trying to inflate the layout of C in A and B, but it didn't work.

This is the scrolllistener on recycler view (fragments A and B):

```
View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_A, container, false);
recyclerView = (RecyclerView) view.findViewById(R.id.myChannelsRecyclerView);
tabLayout = (SmartTabLayout) view.findViewById(R.id.tabs);

recyclerView.addOnScrollListener(new HideShowScrollListener() {
                @Override
                public void onHide() {
                    //tabLayout.animate().translationY(250);
                    //tabLayout return null

                }

                @Override
                public void onShow() {
                    //tabLayout.animate().translationY(0);
                    //tabLayout return null again
                }
    });
```

I should note that `HideShowScrollListener()` is a helper method which is written by me.

**fragment_A.xml:**

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
        android:id="@+id/myChannelsRecyclerView"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:visibility="visible" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

**main_fragment.xml** *(fragment C)*

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <come.example.CustomViewPager
        android:id="@+id/pager"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="1"/>

    <smartertablayout.SmartTabLayout
        android:id="@+id/tabs"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        app:stl_dividerThickness="1dp"
        app:stl_defaultTabTextSize="9sp"
        app:stl_distributeEvenly="true"
        app:stl_indicatorThickness="0dp"/>

</LinearLayout>
```

Main fragment (fragment C in example) is responsible to change and replace the other fragments (A and B) using a pager. It somehow is the parent of this fragments

Comment: I'm not sure I understand what you want to accomplish. But seems that whatever it is, you want to sync 2 scroll views somehow. Now, if they are nested I'll advise against it because things can get quite complex. If they are NOT nested, I'll suggest you take care with translations because touches and areas that otherwise would be off screen don't work exactly as one would expect. Can you give us a mock up drawing of how things should look before and after a scroll?

Comment: No, it's not about syncing. Simply, I want to be able to hide the tabLayout whenever the recycler views are scrolled. Bur as I say the problem is that these two views are placed on distinct layouts @Fabio

Comment: I'm still not sure if the problem is about inflation or hiding views. If inflation, convert fragment to view and nest it there. What is it not doing as expected?

Comment: I updated my question :) @Fabio

Comment: I think the solution to this is to use an interface. Don’t directly reference your tab layout in your recycler fragment, rather create an interface that you can use as a callback in your scroll listener. Implement the interface in your main fragment then you can animate the tab layout in the implemented method. Should work . . . I think.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
//something like this from my suggestion above

class Fragment_A extends Fragemnt{

    YourScollListener animateCallback;
    RecyclerView recyclerView;

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                         Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_A, container, false);
        recyclerView = (RecyclerView) view.findViewById(R.id.myChannelsRecyclerView);

        recyclerView.addOnScrollListener(new HideShowScrollListener() {
            @Override
            public void onHide() {
                animateCallback.animate();
            }

            @Override
            public void onShow() {

            }
       });

        return view;
    }

     public void onAttach(Context context) {
            super.onAttach(context);
            animateCallback = (YourScrollListener) getParentFragment();
     }

     public interface YourScrollListener{
        void animate();
     }

}


//main frag

class Main_Fragment extends Fragemnt implements YourScrollListener{

    animate(){
        //do stuff
    }

}
```

Comment: Happy to see an answer :) I'm very thankful. but look! it seems that `animateCallback` returns null

Comment: I'm now using `animateCallback = (YourScrollListener) getFragmentManager.findFragmentByTag(MainFragment.getTag());` and it's greatly working! Thanks for the clue :)